# h:message elements with for attribute do not present messages in JSF 2

Tags: java, jsf-2, glassfish, facelets

I have the following authentication form in JSF running on Glassfish 3:

```
<h:messages globalOnly="true" errorClass="erro" />
<h:form id="form-login">
    <h:outputText value="User" />
    <h:message for="login-user" />
    <h:inputText id="login-user" 
        value="#{authenticationBean.user}" showMessages="true" />

    <h:outputText value="Password" />
    <h:inputSecret id="login-password" 
        value="#{authenticationBean.password}" />

    <h:commandButton id="Log in" 
        action="#{authenticationBean.logIn}" value="Autenticar-se" />
</h:form>
```

The `authentication.logIn` method is the one below:

```
public String logIn() {
    user = userDAO.authenticate(user, password);
    if (user != null) {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Welcome!");
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        return "ok";
    } else {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Authentication failed");
        message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        if ("".equals(user)) {
            message = new FacesMessage("You need to give a user");
            message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                "login-user", message);
        }
        return "fail";
    }
}
```

I try to show an specific message if the user login is not given, with the line `<h:message for="login-user" />`. It does not work, though: if I click in the submit button with an empty user field, the `<h:messages globalOnly="true" errorClass="erro" />` element presents the `"Authentication failed"` but the `<h:message for="login-user" />` component just does not present the `"You need to give a user"` text as I expected. Instead it presents no message at all. Also, the following warning appears on the log:

```
[lifecycle] WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=login-user[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(You need to give a user), detail=(You need to give a user)]
```

(Actually, I looked for some translation in Google, since the real message I got is in Portuguese:

```
INFO: WARN: FacesMessage(s) foram enfileirados, mas podem não ter sido exibidos.
sourceId=login-usuario[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(You need to give a user), detail=(You need to give a user)]
```

)

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to specify the client ID, not the component ID. Based on the given view code, that'll be:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
    "form-login:login-user", message);
```

If that doesn't work, you need to open the page in browser and view its generated HTML source. It should be the same as `id` attribute of generated HTML `<input>` element.

---

Unrelated to the problem, I usually use `null` as client ID and use a `<h:messages globalOnly="true">` for general validation errors. You may want to take the same approach. For the "You need to give an user" part I'd just use `required="true"` instead.

Comment: Thanks, BalusC! In fact, I use global messages a lot, they are very practical. However, I still have a doubt: how could I programmaticly  get this client id for a component? I suppose it is not very practical to hardcode it in the application...

Comment: For that you'd normally use a validator. Just throw a `ValidatorException` in case of failure and JSF will take care about the client ID.